# Connect to server with Powershel via ssh/scp with Password programmatically

Tags: powershell, ssh, scp

If I try to connect to my Ubuntu server from powershell like this:

```
ssh root@123.456.789.123
```

or this:

```
scp C:\Users\User1\Documents\public\file.txt root@123.456.789.123:temp2.txt
```

I get back request for type password:

```
root@123.456.789.123's password:
```

Is there any way, I can type that password from that powershell script?
Something like:

```
ssh root@123.456.789.123
Write-Output "PasswordToMyServer"
```

Thanks!

Comment: There are already well-known ways to set passwordless entry. https://interworks.com/blog/2021/09/15/setting-up-ssh-agent-in-windows-for-passwordless-git-authentication/

Comment: Search on setting up OpenSSH on Windows.